# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3.3

Tags: android

I received the gradle error (module:app) when I try to install the repository it shows that the required package is not available from the internet. Also, I am an Ubuntu user.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.subhashini.techloggia"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3.3', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
}
```

Comment: Post the error log please.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio open sdk manager and update android support repository to  47.0.0v.

Answer (score 0):

Without your error logs it is impossible to know if this is the only issue, but I suspect the cause of the error is that [espresso version 2.2.2](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html) is the latest version (at least, that I am aware of).

Change the version number from `2.3.3` to `2.2.2`.

Comment: sir i have done.. but now it is showing about 7 java related errors

Comment: @Subhashini What are the new errors? Update your question with the logs please.

Comment: actually the main reason of errors occurred as i saved images with numbers as their name in drawable directory...now i cleared all... thank you sir